# Contact PHP file not loading on Submit

Tags: php, forms, email

Got this HTML contact form:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="get">
    Nombre<br>
    <input type="text" name="cf_name"><br>
    Email<br>
    <input type="text" name="cf_email"><br>
    Mensaje<br>
    <textarea name="cf_message"> </textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

And a separate php file sending contact info:

```
$mail_to = 'tienda@shambricolage.com';
$subject = 'Mensaje de Contacto de Sham Bricolage - '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'Persona de contacto: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail de contacto: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Mensaje: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'De: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Responder a: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Gracias por su mensaje');
        window.location = 'contacto.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('No se pudo enviar. Por favor, contacte por email a tienda@shambricolage.com');
        window.location = 'contacto.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

On form submit, page does not load and web keeps loading with no email sending at all. You can check this on http://www.shambricolage.com/Contacto.html when submiting form, nothing loads.

Done on a tool called Webpage Maker

Comment: Thats not all of your PHP Code or ?

Comment: instead of that javascript `window.location` try `header('Location: contacto.html'); exit();` which is php and should do the same

Comment: This is teh whole php file, the rest is an entire HTML web with no php at all, what i posted is the whole php content

Comment: i am about to try superdj

Comment: @SuperDJ That would probaly not work for him in this case, because he wants to give people a message before redirecting. Ontopic: When clicking the button the page takes infinity time to load. You might be causing an infinite loop somewhere in your code that is not visible to us?

Comment: Instead you could also `echo` the error message and at the end a link back to the form. It might not be exactly what you want but it should solve the problem for now

Comment: Dennis, there's no more code related tan what I have posted. I am about to chanbge all to $_POST and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after contacting hosting team, it was an STMP server and I had to fill a complete PHP mail file with aditional information, as seen on here.

```
<?php


error_reporting( E_ALL & ~( E_NOTICE | E_STRICT | E_DEPRECATED ) ); //Aquí se genera un control de errores "NO BORRAR NI SUSTITUIR"
require_once "Mail.php"; //Aquí se llama a la función mail "NO BORRAR NI SUSTITUIR"

$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
    $field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
    $field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];


$to = 'tienda@shambricolage.com'; //Aquí definimos quien recibirá el formulario
$from = 'tienda@shambricolage.com'; //Aquí definimos que cuenta mandará el correo, generalmente perteneciente al mismo dominio
$host = '217.116.0.228'; //Aquí definimos cual es el servidor de correo saliente desde el que se enviaran los correos
$username = 'tienda.shambricolage.com'; //Aqui se define el usuario de la cuenta de correo
$password = '****'; //Aquí se define la contraseña de la cuenta de correo que enviará el mensaje
$subject = 'Mensaje de la tienda Shambricolage'; //Aquí se define el asunto del correo

    $body = 'Persona de contacto: '.$field_name."\n";
    $body .= 'E-mail de contacto: '.$field_email."\n";
    $body .= 'Mensaje: '.$field_message;

$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
    $field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
    $field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);


if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('No se pudo enviar el mensaje. Por favor, escriba a tienda@shambricolage.com');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
} else {
?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Gracias por su mensaje');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed a bit. Dont know if it works. But its messed up and not well programmed.

HTML:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="GET">
    Nombre<br>
    <input type="text" name="cf_name"><br>
    Email<br>
    <input type="text" name="cf_email"><br>
    Mensaje<br>
    <textarea name="cf_message"> </textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
    ob_start();
    $field_name = $_GET['cf_name'];
    $field_email = $_GET['cf_email'];
    $field_message = $_GET['cf_message'];

    $mail_to = 'tienda@shambricolage.com';
    $subject = 'Mensaje de Contacto de Sham Bricolage - '.$field_name;

    $body_message = 'Persona de contacto: '.$field_name."\n";
    $body_message .= 'E-mail de contacto: '.$field_email."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Mensaje: '.$field_message;

    $headers = 'De: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Responder a: '.$field_email."\r\n";

    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

    if ($mail_status) { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Gracias por su mensaje');
        </script>
    <?php
    header('Location: contacto.html');
    }
    else { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('No se pudo enviar. Por favor, contacte por email a tienda@shambricolage.com');
        </script>
    <?php
    header('Location: contacto.html');
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Won't the header under the script cause a Headers already sent error?

Comment: Dont thaught about that. Thanks. Maybe but iam not sure. But when it cause an Error than use ob_start(); or programm that right

Comment: This gives me an error, sendimg me to this URL: http://www.shambricolage.com/contact.php?cf_name=fer&cf_email=fer&cf_message=+hola

Comment: At least it loads now :) Do you receive any email if you send it? Check your spam

Comment: Put that in the PHP file on top

/* ERROR REPORTING */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);